# Visual Studio Code download existing code

Tags: salesforcedx, visualstudiocode

I have just installed and configured Visual Studio Code. I have authorized my staging organization which contains a grip of apex classes and custom objects. How can I download the existing code into the newly created project?

I get no results with:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve --sourcepath c:\Users\*****\Projects\****\force-app
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Another option is to use the `SFDX: Create Project With Manifest` command in VS Code (equivalent to using `sfdx force:project:create` with the `-x` or `--manifest` option), which will create your project with a `manifest/package.xml` file, that includes wildcard selectors for all the custom code types: ApexClass, ApexComponent, ApexPage, ApexTestSuite, ApexTrigger, and AuraDefinitionBundle, as well as StaticResource. Once you've authorized to a dev org or sandbox org that has code in it, you can use `SFDX: Retrieve Source in Manifest From Org` within VS Code. You can right-click on the package.xml file or use the command palette to find the command. This command is equivalent to `sfdx force:source:retrieve -x ./manifest/package.xml`.

Comment: Nice -- Learned something!

Comment: Thank you for you direction here, it was very helpful.

Comment: Really helpful :)

Answer (score 14):

You don't need `--sourcepath`. It looks at where you are pointing and tries to pull items which match what you have there already.

What you do need is a `package.xml` file to get your entire metadata database; you might need help getting that file for your particular org.

Instead, you can do the following to get going with Apex or Lightning Component development:

```
force:project:create -n MyProject
cd MyProject
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexPage
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m ApexClass
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m AuraDefinitionBundle
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m LightningComponentBundle
```

or you can use this nifty one-liner:

```
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomObject,ApexClass,ApexPage,ApexTrigger,LightningComponentBundle,AuraDefinitionBundle
```

That will populate your source tree, and `--sourcepath` will work when it's pointed at one of those folders.

Comment: Just saw your version. PS you can combine -m params, like `-m CustomObject,ApexClass,ApexPage,ApexTrigger,LightningComponentBundle,AuraDefinitionBundle`.

Comment: I kinda like to spread out the code when teaching!

Comment: Thank you this is very helpful. I wish I could mark two correct answers.